# Migration em varias tabelas com o mesmo prefixo

Tags: php, laravel-5, migrations

É possível com o laravel gerar uma migração que altere varias tabelas com o mesmo prefixo? por exemplo: nas tabelas `pesquisas_187` e `pesquisas_146` (tabelas que possuem os mesmos campos)

```
Schema::table('pesquisas_', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->string('code')->after('name');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe nada pronto no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) para essa ***finalidade***, mas, nada impede a codificação de um [***Migration***](http://Database:%20Migrations) com o seguinte código:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Padrao1 extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME as name FROM information_schema.tables ';
        $sql .= 'where TABLE_SCHEMA=? and TABLE_NAME LIKE ? ';
        $result = DB::select($sql, [getenv('DB_DATABASE'), 'pesquisas_%']);
        foreach($result as $table)
        {
            Schema::table($table->name, function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->string('code')->after('name');
            });
        }
    }

    public function down()
    {

    }
}
```

Nesse código é feito uma pesquisa sobre as tabelas do banco configurada no arquivo `.env` com a chave `DB_DATABASE` (`getenv('DB_DATABASE')`) com um filtro sobre as tabelas do prefixo `pesquisas_`, e seu retorno é uma lista de todas as tabelas que pertence a esse prefixo, o resto é igual utilizando `Schema::table`, como demostrado no código.

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Database: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database)
- [Database: Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations)